# Disable delete but enable move cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm aware of the two methods

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return indexPath.section == 0;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     return YES;
}
```

But how can we disable delete but enable move cells in UITableView?

Comment: Implement the method to return the editing style of the row.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try adding the below delegate methods to your code.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone; 
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Delegate Methods for Swift 3:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .none
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: Please add a description as to what you changed about the code, and why those changes answer the original poster's question.

Comment: Nothing was changed logically about the code. I just provided an answer for users using Swift version 3... let me know if that should be clarified.